# What does redirect in Yaws do in a docker stack?

Tags: docker, yaws

Trying to understand `Yaws` and my docker stack.

I have 3 servers in `yaws.conf`: `domain.tld`, `my.domain.tld` and `sm.domain.tld`. These correspond to containers `www`, `wmy` and `wsm`. I want Yaws to process data from `domain.tld` via appmod and pass through the other two.

With `nginx` as proxy this was not hard to do. How to do it right with `Yaws`?

Currently I pass the same appmod to all three and let that appmod decide what to do.

```
out_check_glue(A) ->    
    {url, Scheme, Host, _Port , Path, Querypart} = yaws_api:request_url(A),
    case Host of
        "my.domain.tld" ->
            Url = "http://" ++ "wmy" ++ Path ++ get_query(Querypart),
?trace('out_check_glue(A)==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++=========CALL WMY============> Url', [Url]),
            vx_request_url(Url);
        "sm.domain.tld" ->
            Url = "http://" ++ "wsm" ++ Path ++ get_query(Querypart),
?trace('out_check_glue(A)==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++=========CALL WSM============> Url', [Url]),
            vx_request_url(Url);
        _ ->
?trace('out_check_glue(A)==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++=========NO GLUE============> Scheme, Host,Path,Querypart', [io:format("~n~n~n~p~n", ["WE START HERE out_check_glue"]),Scheme, Host,Path,Querypart]),
            out_vx(A)
    end.
```

`vx_request_url` just calls `httpc:request` with some further discrimination like for container `adm` as discussed elsewhere, so I have a simple pass through here, `out_vx` starts processing for `www`.

This works well. As you see, the appmod can call the appropriate containers directly. This is easily reproduced in the `yaws` container as well. Enter the container and issue `curl http://wmy` -- voilà.

My idea was to not involve the appmod at all as was the case with `nginx` and pass this decision on to `Yaws` via redirect like so:

```
#        appmods = </, myurl exclude_paths plugins img images styles scripts>
   <redirect>
     / = http://wmy
   </redirect>
```

This does not work as intended: not the container is called but the browser which has to error out, of course: there is no domain `wmy` to be found.

Why is that so and is there a better solution?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included details of any error output or logging output when you try the `<redirect>` approach.

Comment: I do not have any error. Yaws does a redirect to *http://wmy* which is sent to the browser. I expected that this is picked up by the container *wmy* instead, which is the case if I enter the container directly and use curl from there (I get what I want) instead of from the host (*curl: (6) Could not resolve host: wmy*). So obviously the redirect from yaws is issued to the host and not to any container reachable from within the yaws container. This was the trick with nginx: location /wmy { proxy_pass http://wmy; }.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation. I think instead of `<redirect> ... </redirect>` you want 3 virtual servers in your `yaws.conf`: one for `my.domain.tld` containing `<revproxy / http://wmy>`, one for `sm.domain.tld` containing `<revproxy / http://wsm>`, and then a server with the "no glue" part of the appmod.

Comment: Sounds really promising. What am I doing wrong?   `<revproxy / http://wmy>` *Yaws: bad conf: Unexpected input ['<',"revproxy","/","http://wmy",'>'] at line 219 terminating*

Comment: Apologies, I gave you the wrong syntax. It should be `revproxy = / http://wmy`

Comment: Perfect. I'm glad I asked. Having just read the manpage I am sure I could not have found it myself. Thank you very much. You should probably post your answer for upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a redirect, you can use the Yaws reverse proxy feature, as it will essentially do what your appmod is doing in its "no glue" sections.

For `my.domain.tld` and `sm.domain.tld`, add a virtual server to your `yaws.conf` file, and within each, specify `revproxy`:

```
<server my.domain.tld>
    revproxy = / http://wmy
</server>

<server sm.domain.tld>
    revproxy = / http://wsm
</server>
```

Comment: Today I got a crash indicating that `sm.domain.tld` has not been proxied. How come? I'd like to understand this. The crash message is `Req: {http_request,'GET', {abs_path,"/first/second/third?params=1&more=2"}, {1,1}}`. It looks like an intermittent error -- I had this several times, a refresh or adding a random nonsense parameter usually fixed it.

Comment: There's little chance of answering your question based on the information provided. There should be more info preceding the "Req:" message, but either way, this message indicates that some sort of exit or exception occurred during the processing of an `out/1` function, or that function returned a bad value. If you're using `revproxy` then it could be a bug in its `out` functions. But this is a poor forum for trying to get Yaws support; please try the Yaws channel in Erlang Slack, or the erlyaws mailing list, or raise an issue in the Yaws github repo. Try to make a small test case if possible.